# Swift Code in App Delegate to Load Storyboard Causes Crash

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, xcode-storyboard

I have an universal app I am writing and I initially wrote it using two storyboard files.  I had code in the App Delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` routine to decide which storyboard to load and away it would go.  I have since realised that that was a silly thing to do because I had duplicate code, so I have deleted one storyboard and made the other universal.  I have fixed up the VCs to point at the right class and everything.  However, my app now refuses to launch.  When I run it in the sim, it gives me the error

> The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.

.

Here is my code in App Delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var deviceIdiom = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom
    if deviceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
        strDevice = "iPhone"
    } else if deviceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {
        strDevice = "iPad"
    } else {
        strDevice = "Unknown"
    }

    return true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Questions I've already looked at but didn't help):
[Unique Issue displaying first storyboard scene in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991810/unique-issue-displaying-first-storyboard-scene-in-xcode)
[The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272346/the-app-delegate-must-implement-the-window-property-if-it-wants-to-use-a-main-st)
[Managing two storyboards in App Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465996/managing-two-storyboards-in-app-delegate)
[How to manually set which storyboard view to show in app delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559871/how-to-manually-set-which-storyboard-view-to-show-in-app-delegate)
[Swift - Load storyboard programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148067/swift-load-storyboard-programatically)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app delegate needs to start like such:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks what a stupid mistake.  Thanks very much @GoZoner